# GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Im getting this error out of nowhere it used to work just fine. Here is what i have:

in app.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1"
```

in app.gradle end of file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in project gradle file:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
```

And the google-services.json is located in about every folder of my project just to see if it is working.

but still getting the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error, not sure what's the root cause, but as a workaround found a solution.

Downgrade `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'` and it should work, at least it did for me.

Answer (score 8):

After updating to Android Studio 3.3 I started getting the same error. It turns out version `4.1.0` of `com.google.gms:google-services` had a known issue in Android Studio 3.3.

Updating to `com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0` solved the problem for me.