# How to apply Admob code with real App id and unit id..?

Tags: android, admob

I'm very new to Android and I want to launch my first application but I'm facing problem while I'm trying to apply AdMob code in my application.

When I check my code with test ad id it is working fine but when I'm using the same code with my real AdMob App id and Unit id this give me no add in my frame and the Logcat is showing me this.

```
19 5029-5216/com.example.aviralchauhan.demoplayer E/FA: GoogleService failed 
to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string 
resources with name google_app_id.
2019-07-23 12:14:10.330 5029-5216/com.example.aviralchauhan.demoplayer E/FA: 
Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled    2019-07-23 12:14:10.336 5029-5216/com.example.aviralchauhan.demoplayer E/FA: 
Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

As you suggested that this is duplicate question so can you please explain that it's really important to connect the application with firebase to show to ads in my application as I already told you test ads are working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google\_app\_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374463/googleservice-failed-to-initialize-status-10-missing-google-app-id-value-from)

Comment: is firebase dependencies are required to correct the code implementation? because getting same error after apply classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not really necessary to integrate Firebase with Google but it is recommended so as to get detailed statics over how the user acts over your app and their interaction with the app.

Now, the main topic: **Why the add code is not working?**
I am sure that you have something like this in your `manifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

There, the text `YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID` must be replaced by a real ID which you will get by adding your app to the AdMob dashboard. [Check this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356431?hl=en) to get the real ID.

Comment: thanks for your help but already solved and yes it is correct

Comment: What is APPLICATION_ID, should I put the package name of the app here ?

Comment: @PRANAVSINGH are you asking about `com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID`? If yes, then don't change this field, it is the key that Admob integration uses to extract the app id from the manifest. It is not ought to be changed.

Comment: yes It is working perfectly without changing  but also it is showing as a editable field in the docs, please refer to step2 of [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)  link

Comment: well this confused me too for now, as it is a long time since I last used AdMob in any of my projects, but looking at my last project and some other sources online, it seems it should be kept as it is and just change the `YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID` rather than `APPLICATION_ID`
Here are some sources I referred to: [source one](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/android-firebase-admob-all-in-one-2c981275559d)
[source two](https://techstop.github.io/admob-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest>
    <application>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
    android:value="true"/>
</application>
```

set on app AndroidManifest.xml file