# Android studio and emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, apk

[image][image][image]Hello i'm trying to add ad to my android studio project but when I start my emulator , the application keeps stopping . I did everything like I have to do it , 5 times I restarted but always an error . Please help me thanks

Comment: Where's the error you got? Please add it to your post

Comment: Are sure you added the app-id into your AndroidManifest ?

Comment: Hello @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI . Thanks you for helping . I've added picture of my manifest

Comment: Note the `meta-data` tags need to be a direct descendant of the `application` tag as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57184985/17856705.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation will help you according to your problem.
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

You should add this code to your `manifest.xml` file.

```xml
<application
        ...>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

</application>
```

Comment: I already have it

Comment: can you provide more logs of error..?